# IFfing through two (or more) folders to find files matching pattern

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I have a bash-related question. To start the explanation. I had a folder structure looking like this:

```
config--
       |-config-chain.conf
       |-somefile1.txt
       |-somefile2.txt
       |-somefile3.txt
       |-somefile4.txt
       |-somefile5.txt
       |-somefile6.txt
```

`config-chain.conf` contains text looking like this:

```
somefile1
somefile2
somefile3
somefile4
somefile5
somefile6
```

Before today, all those txt files were in one folder, so iterating through this was simple.

But the specification has changed and I have to do this the new way.

```
config--
       |-config-chain.conf
       |
       |--folder1--
                  |-somefile1.txt
                  |-somefile2.txt
                  |-somefile3.txt
       |--folder2--
                  |-somefile4.txt
                  |-somefile5.txt
                  |-somefile6.txt
```

Before that, I was iterating through this with a simple loop. It looked like this:

```
while read config-chain
do
    if [ -f $config-chain.txt ];
    then
        echo "Config file found"
    else
        echo "Config file not found"
    fi
done < config-chain.conf
```

But now the files are in two different folders. My actual approach is looking like this:

```
while read config-chain
do
    if [ -f folder1/$config-chain.txt ] || [ -f folder2/$config-chain.txt ];
    then
        echo "Config file found"
    else
        echo "Config file not found"
    fi
done < config-chain.conf
```

It is looking ugly for me, cause I'm looking for the existence of a file in both folders. I don't know how this will look in the future, maybe there will be 15 folders, so imagine this OR with 15 statements... Is there a way to do this cleaner? Maybe with `find`? Or a more clean way to do this with `IF`?

Comment: Look for *globstar* in bash manual and use `folder*/**/$config-chain` syntax!

Comment: That's beautifully simple, F. Hauri - and it even works without the `folder*`, thus he can just use `shopt -s globstar` and then `**/$config_chain`.

Comment: Oops! My first comment suggest use of `$config-chain` wich is **wrong**! Character `-` could not be part of variablename!! @HansKlünder correctly said!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### globbing and `globstar` under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

There is my demo:

```
mkdir config{,/folder{1,2}}
touch config/{{,folder{1,2}}/somefile1,folder{1,2}/somefile2,folder1/somefile{3,4},folder2/somefile{5,6}}
```

This would create required situation:

```
ls -lR
.:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 4 user user 4096 déc 29 11:13 config

./config:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 déc 29 11:13 folder1
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 déc 29 11:13 folder2
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 déc 29 11:13 somefile1

./config/folder1:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 déc 29 11:13 somefile1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 déc 29 11:13 somefile2
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 déc 29 11:13 somefile3
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 déc 29 11:13 somefile4


./config/folder2:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 déc 29 11:13 somefile1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 déc 29 11:13 somefile2
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 déc 29 11:13 somefile5
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 déc 29 11:13 somefile6
```

Than now:

```
while read config_chain ;do
    cfgfile=(config/**/$config_chain)
    echo ${cfgfile[*]}
  done < <(seq -f somefile%g 1 7)
config/folder1/somefile1 config/folder2/somefile1
config/folder1/somefile2 config/folder2/somefile2
config/folder1/somefile3
config/folder1/somefile4
config/folder2/somefile5
config/folder2/somefile6
config/**/somefile7
```

There is one file missing!!

```
shopt -s globstar
while read config_chain ;do
    cfgfile=(config/**/$config_chain)
        echo ${cfgfile[*]}
  done < <(seq -f somefile%g 1 7)
config/folder1/somefile1 config/folder2/somefile1 config/somefile1
config/folder1/somefile2 config/folder2/somefile2
config/folder1/somefile3
config/folder1/somefile4
config/folder2/somefile5
config/folder2/somefile6
config/**/somefile7
```

Well there it is! Than now:

```
while read config_chain ;do
    for cfgfile in config/**/$config_chain;do
        if [ -f $cfgfile ] ;then
            echo $cfgfile
          fi
      done
  done < <(seq -f somefile%g 1 7)
config/folder1/somefile1
config/folder2/somefile1
config/somefile1
config/folder1/somefile2
config/folder2/somefile2
config/folder1/somefile3
config/folder1/somefile4
config/folder2/somefile5
config/folder2/somefile6
```

Comment: Don't ask me why I've used `seq -f somefile%g 1 7` instead of `printf somefile%d\\n {1..7}`... maybe some characters less to hit ;-)

Comment: I've flagged Your answer as accepted, cause it is working flawlessly, but I cannot use it as a solution in my case cause I cannot use `globstar` in the bash environment I'm using on the terminal server. Still, I need to read more about `globstar`, seems great.

Comment: If you really can't use *globstar* (see `shopt -u`), you could use `config/{folder*/,}$config_chain` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you could use find command like below:

```
filePath=$(find parentDir -name "config-chain.txt")
if [ -z "$filePath" ]
then 
    echo "Config file not found"
else
    echo "Config file found"
fi
```

And in your while loop you could use $filePath instead of config-chain.conf to get input from.

Comment: I'm not sure if `parentDir` is needed... cause I'm IN the `parentDir`. But `-z` is not working - it seems that `-f` is doing the job but I'm still checking it...

Comment: ok then in that case your could use . instead of parentDir. -z checks for variable filePath being not defined or of zero size.

Comment: `-z` showed me "Config file not found" - whenever the file existed or not - but `-f` is working flawlessly :) ANd for the `parentDir` - I'm using a line: `filePath=$(find -name "config-chain.txt")` and its working just fine. could there be any consequences while NOT using the `.`?

Comment: No by default it will search in from current directory only.

Answer (score 0):

dziki, Please note that bash won't accept a '-' as part of a variable name, but it will accept a '_'. Thus

```
read config_chain
```

will work much better than

```
read config-chain
```

Using the underscore would also allow you to replace

```
"config-chain.txt"
```

by

```
"$config_chain.txt"
```

in the answers of almas shaikh and F. Hauri, which in all other respects works fine.